# Botium and WebdriverIO:-Not able to maximizeWindow() [chrome browser]

Tags: javascript, webdriver-io

Trying to invoke a script in `WEBDRIVERIO_OPENBOT` capability in **botium.json**

Script as follows:

```
module.exports = async (container, browser) => {
    await browser.url(`https://www.orangehrm.com/`);
    await browser.maximizeWindow();
    await browser.pause(5000)
}
```

Getting following error:

```
Error: WebDriver error on startup: Command "maximizeWindow" is not yet implemented
```

Answer (score 1):

resolved by setting the capability in botium.json.

```
 "goog:chromeOptions": {
                            "args": ["--start-maximized", "--start-fullscreen"]
                            }
```